# Rendering transparent 3d shape(quad) with equal z-order

Tags: c++, opengl

I render two quads with OpenGL with equal z. When I have DEPTH enabled I get following image, but when it is off I get what I need one fruit over another. Is it possible to draw quads with equal z, as I want? My OGL settings:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND); glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST); glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

[image: my trouble]

**EDIT** sorry I forgot to mention that left topmost quad I call to render first, and I use orthographic

**EDIT +1** when I render quads with different Z I get the same image, how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The z-buffer doesn't care about transparency and so you have to sort the drawing order of your quads by their approximate depth.

I would change their depth to be different (you can use an orthographic projection to have them appear the same size) and then draw the further quad first.

Also, it is never a good idea to draw two polygons at the same depth even without transparency because of [z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).

Comment: You might also find **glDepthFunc** useful.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented and saw that I have same problem when I render cube, so the problem was because of vertices ordering, and possibly backface culling parameters.